# Do we need multiple instances for each namepace when using following php SplClassLoader.php

Tags: php

Well I am just bit confused after comparing the two version of the SplClassLoader

One is here: https://gist.github.com/jwage/221634

Which I think need multiple instances if we have multiple namespaces ,as the implementation suggests

The other one is https://wiki.php.net/rfc/splclassloader , which seems pretty nice but I don't find a git version somewhere.It seems straight forward with add() method to add multiple include paths.

I ll appreciate if someone confirm what I am thinking and suggest me one of the above or better one.

thanks

Comment: I was wondering the same: when using `SplClassLoader` is it required to create an instance for and `register()` each root namespace? Seems like an odd design.

Comment: @MarkFox I decided to use Zend 2 autoloader https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/tree/master/library/Zend/Loader , its nice and clean with multiple interfaces to do this kind of things.This is nice tutorial to start with http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2/using-zendloaderautoloader/

Comment: that one does look nice. Check my answer, you may like both.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that you if you pass `null` for the namespace (the first argument), you're able to load any namespace under the include path (the second argument):

```
$loader = new SplClassLoader( null, 'src');
$loader->register();
```

Typically I've seen example usages of `SplClassLoader` like this:

```
$loader = new SplClassLoader( 'Mine', 'path\to\libs');
$loader->register();

use Mine\Craft;
$c = new Craft;
```

Which is fine if you only want to load classes under the `Mine` namespace. But what if you wanted to use the `Yours` namespace? You could rightly do:

```
$loader = new SplClassLoader( 'Mine', 'path\to\libs');
$loader->register();
$loader = new SplClassLoader( 'Yours', 'path\to\libs');
$loader->register();

use Mine\Craft;
use Your\Hovercraft;

$c = new Craft;
$h = new Hovercraft;
```

But that seems long winded doesn't it? Especially since they are stored in the same place. What if we had three or four namespaces to work with?

If all of your namespaces are in the same directory you can be lazy.
Here is the complete example, `root.php`:

```
require 'SplClassLoader.php';
$loader = new SplClassLoader( null, 'path\to\libs');
$loader->register();

use Mine\Craft;
use Your\Hovercraft;

$c = new Craft;
$h = new Hovercraft;
```

This assumes your directory structure is like this:

```
- path
  - to
    - libs
      - Mine
        - Craft.php
      - Yours
        - Hovercraft.php
root.php
SplClassLoader.php
```

And of course your classes namespacing follows the standard:
`Craft.php`

```
namespace Mine;

class Craft
{
…
}
```

Now, I can't comment on the security of this approach. I suppose it's nice to be able to whitelist certain namespaces? Not sure it's a security feature, seems more like some built-in flexibility so you don't have to put all of your libraries in one spot. For my money though, it's all about brevity and simplicity. Consolidated dependencies, pass `null` and move on with your code.

Comment: +1 for the null approach , but what I desired was single instance to load all namespaces.

Comment: My solution works implicitly for any and all namespaces. Are you saying wanted a way to load multiple *specific* namespaces via one instance?